# rails+rails_admin customize content of a specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin gem.
I'm customizing the edit action of a model, so there are many fields that display by default rails_admin. 
There is a field to select some value using a select box for multiple value.
Is possible to customize the content of this field?  by default rails_admin show me the name of the attribute, but i want to display the name and other attribute like: id and created_at.

Is possible?

***SOLUTION***
in the model of the field to customize:

```
  #app/models/my_model.rb
  rails_admin do
    object_label_method :to_label
  end

  def to_label
    "#{name}-#{attribute}-#{other-attribute}"
  end
```